# Is there online servise that validate video for Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, video

I have link to video file, and i want to check is it supported by Silverlight or not..

The question is - is there an online servise that provide this functionality?

Comment: "mp4 Silverlight video" - whats mp4 silverlight? Silverlight can play mp4, so why do you need to check compatibility?

Comment: opps.. sorry my bad.. not mp4.. just any video..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to play your video in some Silverlight player, here is the HealthMonitor from the SMF/MMPPF: http://smf.cloudapp.net/healthmonitor